# How to make XGBoost model to learn its mistakes

Tags: python, model, xgboost

My XGBoost model regularly makes mistakes in prediction on the same samples. I want to let the model know its mistakes and correct model prediction behavior. How can I do this?

I tried to solve the problem by decreasing logistic regression threshold (by increasing model sensibility) but it leads to radical increasing of false positive predictions. I also tried to tune model' parameters (colsample by tree, subsample, min_child_weight, max_depth), but it didn't help.

In text recognition software I faced some function, which allows to say the program "you predicted a letter incorrectly", and, by this, to learn model to recognize a letter correctly.

Is there something similar in Machine Learning?

May be, there are some regularization methods, which re-distribute weight between features.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you verify if those samples are outliers ? If they are, try to make your model more robust to them by changing the hyperparameters or scaling your data set

Comment: Gabriel, thank you very much. Would you give some examples of hiperparameters which will make a model much robust?

Comment: Take a look at the L1 regularization, but in your case I recommend you to preprocess your data since xgboost is a model that's already robust to outliers, I mean apply some transformation like the log to decrease the skewness of your features it might help, if you are familiar with scikit learn there's the robustscaler

Comment: Gabriel, thank you. I'm not familiar, but will nessessary learn it.